# Making CSS Grid fill all available space in CSS Flexbox column

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-grid

I'm building a new website, and while I am doing that, I thought I'd try out some new technologies to see how they work in practice.

I have a two column website which uses Flexbox for layout, and in the left-hand column, I have four grids using CSS Grids.

What I would like to do is have all four grid squares fill all the available space in the Flexbox column, but I can't for the life of me work out how to do it.

This is my CSS:

```
#flex_wrapper {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
}

#main_content {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex-grow: 4;
    order: 1;
}

#right_menu {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex-grow: 1;
    order: 2;
}

#grid_wrapper {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 800px 800px;
    grid-template-rows: 400px 400px;
}

#grid_item {
    display: grid;
}
```

I have the sizes for the grids hardcoded in at the moment just to make sure that the CSS grid is working but as I said, ideally I'd like all four boxes to take up the whole space in the left-hand column (#main_content), and I have no idea how to do that.

Comment: if I understand you correctly, you need to look at `fr` units, so the end example looks like `grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;`

Comment: A demo would be ideal...but CSS-Grid can't make actual squares dynamically. If *you* make them square, CSS-G can lay them out..

Comment: @Morpheus Awesome! That pretty much solved my problem. It isn't 100% what I was after but it is much better now. I think I can use the grid to split up my content the way that I want to. If you write an answer, I'll accept it as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is [fr unit](https://css-tricks.com/introduction-fr-css-unit/). The example should look like the following:

`grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;`